# Catch tooltip click

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to catch a tooltip click which doesn't fire marker click handler?
For example the following doesn't work

```
var t = L.tooltip({permanent: true, interactive:true}, marker).setLatLng([51.505, -0.09])
                                                              .setContent("test")
                                                              .addTo(map);
t.on('click', function(){
    console.log("tooltip click handler");
});
```

While, with the following clicking the tooltip fires any marker click handler defined

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
var t = L.tooltip({permanent: true, interactive:true}, marker).setLatLng([51.505, -0.09])
                                                              .setContent("test")
                                                              .addTo(map);

marker.bindTooltip(t);
marker.on('click', function(){
    console.log("marker click handler");
});
```

Is it possible to prevent any marker handler defined to be executed when clicking a tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like events are automatically passed to the marker indeed.

A workaround would be to detect whether the `originalEvent` originates from the tooltip's container or not:

**EDIT**

Detecting tooltip's specific class (and using `hasClass` as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class)

```js
marker.on('click', function(event) {
  var originalTarget = event.originalEvent.target;

  if (hasClass(originalTarget, "leaflet-tooltip")) {
    console.log("tooltip click handler");
  } else {
    console.log("marker click handler");
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/114/

---

Original code:

```js
var tooltipContainerId = L.stamp(t._container);

marker.on('click', function(event) {
  var originalTarget = event.originalEvent.target;

  if (L.stamp(originalTarget) === tooltipContainerId) {
    console.log("tooltip click handler");
  } else {
    console.log("marker click handler");
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/111/

Comment: The trick works, although I've to write such test in at least two different event handlers. In addition, checking event.originalEvent.target is a good approach, I can't test for containerId because I've thousand markers (and tooltips).

Comment: Instead of checking the container id, you could try to find a more generic differentiator. CSS classes would probably be a good place to look into.

Comment: @mep here you go with class detection instead of id comparison. See the above edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to take action when tooltip is clicked then you can also do it by making the tooltip a hyperlink that when clicked leads to javascript execution. In order to do this however you must pass the option `interactive: true` when creating the tooltip:

```
layer.bindTooltip(tooltipContentForLayer(layer), {
  interactive: true,
});
```

Where `tooltipContentForLayer()` is defined as:

```
function tooltipContentForLayer(layer) {
  return '<a href="#" onclick="editLabel(\'' + layer.SB_layerId + '\');">' + layer.SB_label + '</a>';
}
```

and

```
function editLabel(layerId) {
  console.log('EDIT ' + layerId);
}
```

`SB_layerId` and `SB_label` are custom attributes I attached to layers previously, e.g. `layer.SB_layerId = 2;`.